# Access Rails Method Defined In Model Through View In Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

I have a method defined in my controller that I am trying to create a button or form to access.

Model

```
class DoThis < ActiveRecord::Base

 def take_action(a, b)

 end

end
```

View

```
<%= @do_this.take_action(@a, @b) %>
```

I would like to convert the above code in the View to a button_to or form_for but cannot figure out how.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't do this. Models should never contain view code - it's intentionally not easy to do that, because it breaks MVC. Instead, you should add a helper function in your `app/helpers/controller_name_helper.rb` file.

```
def take_action(obj)
  button_to( ... )
end
```

Then, you'll just call `<%=take_action(@do_this) %>` in your view.

Comment: Would I put the additional code that is currently defined in the "take_action" method in the Model into the new "take_action" method in the controller helper?

Comment: I defined the action in the controller helper instead of the model and now I am running into another problem.  The code I had inside of "take_action" was to update.attributes on another model--DoThisTwo.  The code worked properly when it was defined in the original DoThis model but now I am getting a NoMethodError with "undefined mehtod 'attribute' when it is in the CONTROLLER of DoThis.  I added attr_accessible for the attribute I am updating in DoThisTwo.  Any other suggestions?